# Do Login Flows Get Triggered when attepting to "Login As" another User?

Tags: login, grant-login-access, loginflow, delegated-authentication

I'd like to create "Test Users" for QA personnel to login into Production during deployment. I want to use delegate administration so I can manually login as these test users and grant account login access to QA personnel. I'd like to add extra security and use a "Login Flow" to only allow QA personnel to login as the Test Users during Support Hours. My question is does the "Login as" link trigger a Login Flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spoke to our Salesforce team that owns this feature and confirmed that when logging in as another user that has login flows on their profiles, the admin user is not subject to login flows.

And when an admin user has login flows on their profile and they log in as another user, the admin user isn't subject to login flows when they click the Login link. The admin still has to complete login flows when they login to the app with their own user credentials.

We are also working on documenting this information about how Login As and Login Flows interact and will update this thread as I have more information. Thank you